# How can I find the previous row in a DataFrame with a Timestamp index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to zero the last NaN at the start of a DataFrame in Pandas. My DataFrame objects have timestamps in.

**Example data**

If I have this data:

```
In [228]: my_df
Out[228]: 
            blah
1990-01-01   NaN
1990-01-02   NaN
1990-01-03   NaN
1990-01-04   NaN
1990-01-05   NaN
1990-01-06     5
1990-01-07     6
1990-01-08     7
1990-01-09   NaN
1990-01-10     9

[10 rows x 1 columns]
```

I want to get the following (changing the value on the 5th of January):

```
            blah
1990-01-01   NaN
1990-01-02   NaN
1990-01-03   NaN
1990-01-04   NaN
1990-01-05     0
1990-01-06     5
1990-01-07     6
1990-01-08     7
1990-01-09   NaN
1990-01-10     9

[10 rows x 1 columns]
```

**What I've tried**

I can get the index after the last NaN:

```
In [229]: ts = my_df['blah'].first_valid_index()

In [230]: ts
Out[230]: Timestamp('1990-01-06 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

I've found this ugly approach:

```
my_df['blah'][:ts][-2] = 0
```

However, this will throw `IndexError` if my DataFrame doesn't have any NaNs at the start. What would a better solution look like (presumably without just writing a for loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just handle the `IndexError` with a `try..except`:

```
try:
    df.loc[:ts, 'blah'][-2] = 0
except IndexError:
    pass
```

or an `if-statement`:

```
s = df.loc[:ts, 'blah']
if len(s) > 1: 
    s[-2] = 0
```

Since `:ts` is a basic slice, `s` is a view. So modifying `s` modifies `df`.